# Como atribuir um estilo a todos objetos de uma só vez em WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

É possivel criar um style em WPF onde será utilizando para todos os componentes do mesmo tipo, sendo assim não necessario a chamada do Style para o componente?

Minha ideia é criar um estilo como por exemplo

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">

 </Style>
```

E todos os buttons que não tem nenhum estilo associados carreguem o estilo desse local, sem que seja necessario eu indicar a key do estilo para o button.

Do mesmo modo que ocorre com o css, eu referencio um estilo para "p" e todos os "p" recebem aquele estilo.

Comment: Já tentou colocar o style no App.xaml?

Comment: Sim, mas é necessario referenciar com uma key não é?

Answer (score 0):

Estilos globais no WPF podem ser feitos da seguinte maneira:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
...
</Style>
```

Isso se aplicaria a todos que são do tipo `TextBox` ou que herdam de `TextBox`.

Para deixar esse estilo global, coloque o estilo dentro de um `ResourceDictionary` no App.xaml.

Comment: Acabei de testar isso aplicando um estilo para todas as row de um datagrid ...  `<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </Trigger>                   
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>`

Comment: Colocou num ResourceDictionary?

Comment: Tenhos vários estilos dentro do ResourceDictionary ... devo colocar ele em um ResourceDictionary Separado?

Comment: Não, seria no mesmo. Você chegou a testar seu estilo separadamente, só em uma tela pra ver se ele te dá o resultado esperado?

Comment: Testei em varias telas e nada

Comment: E quando eu coloco uma key ele funciona, eu uso também o  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow} quando eu utilizo com a key, porém sem a key ele não funciona